# using async await to listen for messages

Tags: .net, silverlight-5.0, async-await

I want to implement silverlight's localmessaging using async await.

Lets say I created a method, `ListenTask()`, that returns a message wrapped in a Task using LocalMessageReceiver's `Listen` method and Message Received event.
How can I use async await and process messages as I receive them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're expecting many messages, not just one, this is likely a better fit for Reactive Extensions - Observable.FromEvent and then subscribe.  Task is a good fit for a single future value, IObservable is a good fit for a 'stream' of future values.

With Rx 2.0, you can use await with observables if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

James Manning's answer is a good one; however if you did want to use async/await you can certainly use the [Dataflow library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603.aspx) to accomplish 'streamed' asynchronous message passing quite robustly.

Comment: Thank you but I don't want to use an other library. I was trying out something with async/await itself.